# Difference between using module, Import-Module, and #requires -Modules

Tags: powershell

Is there any detailed reference for how these 3 different methods for importing PowerShell modules work? I'm currently seeing different behavior with `using module` vs `Import-Module` in a script.

It seems importing dependencies works differently. Using `Import-Module` in order of dependencies can resolve the issue, but with `using module` it doesn't appear to be able to resolve dependencies.

Is this script dependent on how the import statements are created or is there a documented difference in how these different commands work?

Comment: Does this help? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.1#importing-classes-from-a-powershell-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.1#importing-classes-from-a-powershell-module)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm aware of the various docs on each method. I'm looking for a better understanding of why each method exists and the intended use. The docs suggest this, but I was hoping the PowerShell team discussed this somewhere.

Comment: Each was introduced in a different version of PowerShell, for differing reasons.  `Import-Module` is the original, introduced in PowerShell 2.0 to support module development.  `#Requires -Modules` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0 to prevent scripts from running unless the required modules were present and loaded.  `Using Module` was added in PowerShell 5.0 to support class development; specifically, loading classes from modules, which neither `Import-Module` nor `#Requires -Modules` can do.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find any guidelines either, but I made the following comparison to make some sense of what is what.

## [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.2)

Well, it's a cmdlet. That means it

- Accepts pipelines: `'PSReadLine','PSColor' | Import-Module`
- Accepts splatting: `$params = @{Name = 'PSReadLine'; OutBuffer = 1} ; Import-Module @params`
- Supports flags and parameters: `Import-Module -PassThru PSReadLine`
- Can be called almost everywhere: `function Load {Import-Module PSReadLine}`

Therefore, it is well suited for ad-hoc module loading and dynamic reloading.

## [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.2)

`using` is a keyword, so it's not something you can pass around like `Import-Module`. It doesn't take parameters the same way as cmdlets do, and it does not work with pipelines. In short, it's a primitive. Yet another limitation is that it has to be placed on top of the script, before all other statements.

A case when you need to use `using module` is when you want to load classes and enums. Neither `Import-Module` nor `#Requires` will add classes defined in a module into your scope. Generally speaking, it's designed for casual module loading.

## [`#Requires -Modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.2)

This is used to assert that certain modules are loaded (amongst others). In contrast to the rest, this command fails if the module cannot be loaded with `Import-Module`. Another difference is that it works only in scripts -- it does nothing in shell.

Comment: This ammends your answer really well: https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules