# PowerShell - Why Am I Getting a "Unable to Find Type" Error?

Tags: powershell

A script running in Visual Studio Code (VSC) returns this error:

```
Write-Error: Unable to find type [SERVER_TYPE].
…
PositionMessage: At C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Powershell\Modules\TchPublisherArguments\TchPublisherArguments.psm1:94 char:27
+    [Parameter(mandatory)] [SERVER_TYPE]$server
```

The error occurs here:

```
function Show-LastUploadTime {
param (
   [Parameter(mandatory)] [SERVER_TYPE]$server
)
```

The SERVER_TYPE is defined in module **TchPublisherUploader**. Here’s the beginning of **TchPublisherArguments**, which both requires and imports **TchPublisherUploader**:

```
#Requires -Modules AtomwareCommons
#Requires -Modules TchPublisherUploader

Import-Module -name AtomwareCommons
Import-Module -name TchPublisherUploader

Set-Strict Mode -Version Latest
```

In **TchPublisherUploader**, the enum is defined as follows:

```
enum SERVER_TYPE {   # Server receiving the uploaded files
   remote            # The server hosting the public-facing Web site
   local             # An SFTP server running on the user’s computer. Used for testing.
}
```

In **TchPublisherUploader**, VSC reports the SERVER_TYPE enum has 22 references to it, **including the one where the error is occurring**. When I click on the reference to the error line, it goes to that line in **TchPublisherArguments** as expected.

In addition, when I Ctrl-Click on SERVER_TYPE in **TchPublisherArguments**, I'm taken to the enum definition in **TchPublisherUploader**, which is what I would expect.

The VSC folder pane shows no problem markers on any of the files.

My $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Unless someone has a better suggestion, I may be forced to bite the bullet and create a module manifest. But adding more complexity scares me, as this framework seems to break every time I turn around. Is a module manifest more robust than simple Requires & Import statements?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `enum` __before__ it's being used by your function?

Comment: "Inside the imported module" - in the same _file_?

Comment: Santiago - Not sure what you mean. The enum is declared in a different module (TchPublisherUploader). The error occurs in a module named TchPublisherArguments.

Comment: If the `enum` comes from a different module, have you added this module in the `RequiredModules` section of your `psd1` module and when importing your module, are you targeting the `psd1` instead of the `psm1` ?

Comment: Whoa -- it works! But now I'm baffled, I've been running this script for months without using RequiredModules and no psd1 module. Why did it work then?

Comment: I spoke too soon. It ran without error, but I was debugging a different command line arg, so it didn't call the offending function. I'm going to amend original question to show my current configuration.

Comment: A server type is either Remote or Local.  You are trying to cast a server to a server type which doesn't make any sense : [SERVER_TYPE]$server  Isn't the type a property?

Comment: "I've been running this script for months without using RequiredModules and no psd1 module" This probably worked before because the other that had this `enum` defined was previously imported either explicitly (`Import-Module`) or implicitly (by using any `cmdlet` / `function` from that module). By adding the other module to `RequiredModules` you're telling PowerShell that __before__ any cmdlet or function from your current module the other module __needs to be loaded beforehand__

Comment: "Is a module manifest more robust than simple Requires & Import statements?" of course it is. Manifests are a fundamental part of PowerShell Modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the mystery: The code needed **using module TchPublisherUploader** instead of **Import-Module**, because Import-Module can not handle enums.

See Stack Overflow thread at [Difference between using module, Import-Module, and #requires -Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455543/difference-between-using-module-import-module-and-requires-modules) for the nitty gritty details.